# C: Undefined behavior when multiplying uint16_t?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, signed-overflow

I've realized and read that multiplying a `uint16_t` with another `uint16_t` results in an integer (it actually seems to be a signed integer? see: ). Given that, do I have to assume that the following function `f` produces undefined behavior, because there'll be a signed integer overflow?

The overflow would occur, because `x*x` for `x=45000` results in "almost" `INT32_MAX` and it will then overflow if it is multiplied again by `x`.

(btw: on my platform `int` is a `int32_t`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t f(uint16_t x) {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(x));     // <-- 2
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(x * x)); // <-- 4
    return x * x * x;
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t x = 45000;
    uint16_t y = f(x);
}
```

The overflow would occur, because `x*x` for `x=45000` results in "almost" `INT32_MAX` and it will then overflow if it is multiplied again by `x`.

Is this correct, or do I make some wrong assumptions?

Comment: Unrelated, but note that the `sizeof` operator returns a value of type `size_t`. The correct `printf` format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`. Mismatching format-specifier and argument type leads to UB.

Comment: What, in your own words, do you think `sizeof( x * x )` does?

Comment: Also note that in almost all cases, `sizeof` is a compile-time operation. The expression used for the `sizeof` operator is not evaluated at run-time.

Comment: More related to your question: Because of [usual arithmetic conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) the compiler will perform [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) so `x * x` will be performed as `int` values with an `int` result. That `int` result may then be [converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions) to a smaller type.

Comment: Should "_See:_" be followed by a link or citation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that your posted code will invoke undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow.

According to [§6.3.1.1 ¶2 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2), the `uint16_t` operands will both get promoted to an `int`, because an `int` is 32-bits wide on your platform and therefore able to represent all values representable by `uint16_t`. If this were not the case, then the operands would get promoted to `unsigned int`.

Therefore, on platforms on which `int` is 32 bits wide, you will be getting a signed integer overflow (which is undefined behavior), whereas on platforms on which `int` is 16 bits wide, you will be getting an unsigned integer overflow (which is not undefined behavior).

Comment: "is not undefined behavior" [Bilbo worthy](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/310592/51392)--> better as "is defined behavior".

Answer (score 5):

> do I have to assume that the following function f produces undefined behavior, because there'll be a signed integer overflow?

Yes, on 32-bit `int/unsigned` implementations.  No signed integer overflow on 16-bit `int/unsigned` ones.

> The overflow would occur, because x*x for x=45000 results in "almost" `INT32_MAX` and it will then overflow if it is multiplied again by x.

Yes and `int` overflow is *undefined behavior* (UB).

To avoid `int` overflow UB, use `unsigned` math and let the compiler emit efficient code.  Works well for `int/unsigned` as 16, 32, ... bit widths.

```
// return x * x * x;
return 1u * x * x * x;  // Coerce into using unsigned math
```